# When does Ti.Storekit Module invoke finishTransaction?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, titanium-mobile, storekit, titanium-modules

*Titanium SDK version* : `1.8.1`
*Platform & version* : `iOS 5.1`
I'm developping *iOS* application using *Titanium Mobile*. And this application includes *In-App Purchase* using `Ti.Storekit` module.
I'm troubled about *In-App Purchase* system.

According to Apple's documentation, when purchase transaction is complete, my application needs to invoke `finishTransaction` method.
However, `finishTransaction` method is not specified in `Ti.Storekit` module...
Then, my question is beow:

1. When does `Ti.Storekit` Module invoke `finishTransaction`? (And is it automatically?)
2. Can my application invoke `finishTransaction` optional time?

Thank you.

Comment: when you are using 3rd part code in you application, you should ask the author of the code about anything. :(